# Extract specific string from a line in unix

Tags: unix, grep

I have a line as shown below and I'm trying to extract strings which matches the given pattern using grep command. But it is not working as expected.

```
# file: /test/test1 # owner: own # group: grp user::rwx user:nr:rwx user:ac:rwx user:ao:rwx group::r-x group:accounts:--x group:fin:r-x mask::rwx other::--- default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:group:accounts:--x default:group:fin:rwx default:mask::rwx default:other::---
```

Pattern to be serached

`default:group:.*`

Command used

```
echo "# file: /test/test1 # owner: own # group: grp user::rwx user:nr:rwx user:ac:rwx user:ao:rwx group::r-x group:accounts:--x group:fin:r-x mask::rwx other::--- default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:group:accounts:--x default:group:fin:rwx default:mask::rwx default:other::---" | grep -o "default:group:.*" | grep -o "rwx"
```

Expected output

`default:group:fin:rwx`

Actual result

`default:group:accounts:--x default:group:fin:rwx default:mask::rwx default:other::---`

Comment: Pattern is giving correct results, since you are using greedy match `.*` and there are more than 1 match of string `default` so which default you want to use? Any specific pick/conditions here?

Comment: I should get the string which starts with ```default:group``` and ends with ```rwx``` as result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`default:group:.*` is not exact enough as there are multiple matches for that:

```
$ echo "# file: /test/test1 # owner: own # group: grp user::rwx user:nr:rwx user:ac:rwx user:ao:rwx group::r-x group:accounts:--x group:fin:r-x mask::rwx other::--- default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:group:accounts:--x default:group:fin:rwx default:mask::rwx default:other::---"|
grep -o "default:group:[^ ]*"
```

outputs

```
default:group::r-x
default:group:accounts:--x
default:group:fin:rwx
```

You need to

```
$ echo ... | grep -o "default:group:fin:[^ ]*"
```

or pick the third match.

**Update**: Just noticed *starts with `default:group` and ends with `rwx`* in the comments:

```
$ echo ... | grep -o "default:group:[^ ]*rwx "
```

Comment: I have tried with below scenario
```echo '# file: /test/test1 # owner: own # group: sgg-omn-ds-acc user::rwx group::r-x other::r-x default:user::rwx default:group::r-x default:group:fin:r-- default:group:fins:r-x default:mask::rwx default:other::r-x ' | grep -o "default:group:[^ ]*r-x"```
But it give the result as ```default:group::r-x``` & ```default:group:fins:r-x```. But i need only this result ```default:group:fins:r-x```

Comment: Then _ends with `rwx`_ is not valid anymore and you need to be more exact which renders regex meaningless: `... | grep -o "default:group:fins:r-x"`